# Admob Interstitial Are Showing After App Close

Tags: android, admob

I am just implementing admob on my one android application.I am requesting to  admob for show   interstitial ads on app menu screen .But on that time if i exit from  the application & admob request is not received yet due to slow internet connection.So admob are showing interstitial after some time on my phone screen. Is this google ad policy violation ?? .Because admob not give any method for stop interstitial ads (Google Product) if it is not received yet.

Comment: You should call the interstitial isReady() method before show()

Comment: It's a shame that google haven't provided a `onPause` and `onResume` for Interstitial that can automatically detect and not show ad when app goes to background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call finish on the activity, if possible.

If not, why not set a flag using onPause or onStop events, check this flag before calling show () on the interstitial.

Comment: I am calling Show interstitial on OnReceived method which is admob interface.I am also calling finish methos but still it is showing

Comment: Just check the flag before calling show() in onReceiveAd event.

Comment: Hmm thanks also let me know if  i dont handle it. It is google play policy violation ??

Comment: Showing ads after the user quit your app? I would assume it is against Admob Terms of service.

Comment: Actully i am not calling admob on exit of application.But some times due to slow internet connection it displaying after exit of application.But some time

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. Even if it's not against Admob TOS (Though I believe it is), from the UX prespective it's intrusive and you should really avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
android:noHistory="true"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|
uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Just add `android:noHistory="true"` in the manifest file it should work.